# Not showing the image in RecyclerView

Tags: android, imageview, android-recyclerview

i'm starting in Android programming.
I have a problem since a few days and i want ask you if you can help me.
I want to show a recyclerView with different layouts ,text and image.
I have this code ,the first type ,text is working ,but the image not appears.

Thanks.

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Historias object = mList.get(position);
    if (object != null) {
        switch (object.getTipoHistoria()) {
            case tipo_texto:
                ((CityViewHolder) holder).mTitle.setText(object.getTexto());
                break;
            case tipo_imagen:

                StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://xx.appspot.com/imagenes/un-gato-bebe-433.jpg");

                storageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        new RetrieveFeedTask().execute(uri.toString());

                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        // Handle any errors
                    }
                }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                        ((EventViewHolder) holder).mImage.setImageBitmap(feed);
                    }
                });

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend use special lib for downloading photos from web or sd. Here some:

---

[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

```
Picasso.with(context).load("path_to_image").into(imageView);
```

[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

```
Glide.with(this).load("path_to_image").into(imageView);
```

Comment: This answer is spot on, however Picasso has changed a tiny bit since this was posted. In order to utilise Picasso as Andrey suggests, you'll need to use the following syntax:
`Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove switch case,  as you know when user enters switch statement only 1 case will be executed, so only your set text was getting executed not the image one

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Historias object = mList.get(position);

                 holder.mTitle.setText(object.getTexto());


                StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://xx.appspot.com/imagenes/un-gato-bebe-433.jpg");

                storageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        new RetrieveFeedTask().execute(uri.toString());

                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        // Handle any errors
                    }
                }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                        holder.mImage.setImageBitmap(feed);
                    }
                });


        }
    }
}
```

and i would suggest you to use picasso or glide library to load images ,its super easy to load images

Edit.

just use `holder` . instead of  `((EventViewHolder) holder)`